# How can I more efficiently distribute these tasks into batches?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have data files separated into months, and am clustering node.js to separate the jobs into batches for different threads to handle, but the way I'm doing it leaves some threads with no work to do, like so:

```
thread 1 selection [ '2004-05', '2004-06', '2004-07', '2004-08' ]
thread 2 selection [ '2004-09', '2004-10', '2004-11', '2004-12' ]
thread 9 selection [ '2007-01', '2007-02', '2007-03', '2007-04' ]
thread 7 selection [ '2006-05', '2006-06', '2006-07', '2006-08' ]
thread 5 selection [ '2005-09', '2005-10', '2005-11', '2005-12' ]
thread 4 selection [ '2005-05', '2005-06', '2005-07', '2005-08' ]
thread 8 selection [ '2006-09', '2006-10', '2006-11', '2006-12' ]
thread 6 selection [ '2006-01', '2006-02', '2006-03', '2006-04' ]
thread 10 selection [ '2007-05', '2007-06', '2007-07', '2007-08' ]
thread 3 selection [ '2005-01', '2005-02', '2005-03', '2005-04' ]
thread 11 selection [ '2007-09', '2007-10', '2007-11', '2007-12' ]
thread 0 selection [ '2004-01', '2004-02', '2004-03', '2004-04' ]
thread 15 selection []
thread 14 selection []
thread 13 selection []
thread 12 selection [ '2008-01', '2008-02', '2008-03' ]
```

See, threads 13, 14 and 15 get no work to do, wasting cores on my machine. Here's my code, ignoring the cluster boilerplate code, just assume i is equal to the thread's number (0-15 in my case):

```
let dateStart = moment('2004-01-02');
let dateEnd = moment('2008-03-02');
let timeValues = [];
while (dateEnd > dateStart || dateStart.format('M') === dateEnd.format('M')) {
  timeValues.push(dateStart.format('YYYY-MM'));
  dateStart.add(1, 'month');
}
let i = parseInt(process.env.workerId);
let monthBatchCount = Math.ceil(timeValues.length / cpus);
let selectionStart = i * monthBatchCount;
let selectionEnd = selectionStart + monthBatchCount;
let selection = timeValues.slice(selectionStart, selectionEnd)
console.log("thread", i, "selection", selection)
```

How can I alter my approach to more efficiently distribute the jobs into batches so that no threads get left with empty batches?

Comment: Do these units of work need to grouped contiguously like this, or could they be randomly distributed instead?

Comment: @Jacob they can be randomly distributed in this case, it's a one-off batch job processing 10GB .csv files into a db.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to have each worker pull units of work from the main thread instead of pushing work to them. The parent thread would work as the broker of units of work, and workers, once spawned, ask for work, perform the work, then ask for more work in a loop.

```
// Parent code

const unitsOfWork = [...];
const workers = [...];

workers.forEach(worker => {
  worker.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.type === 'CLAIM_WORK') {
      const unit = unitsOfWork.pop();
      const message = unit ? { type: 'WORK', unit } : { type: 'WORK_FINISHED' };
      worker.postMessage(message);
    }
  });
});
```

```
// Worker code

const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads');

parentPort.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.type === 'WORK') {
    performWork(message.unit);
    parentPort.postMessage({ type 'CLAIM_WORK' });
  } else if (message.type === 'WORK_FINISHED') {
    // Exit?
  }
});

parentPort.postMessage({ type 'CLAIM_WORK' });
```

Comment: Yes, that's definitely true Jacob, I'm using that kind of system elsewhere in my project, and it's an intuitive system neatly pulling tasks from a queue, but that involves setting up a messaging cycle between worker and master, which involves significantly more coding than just dividing an array out into proper batches. Thanks for all you do on this site btw, you've helped me numerous times over the years here (spanning multiple accounts, since I have a fear of anyone I know every discovering my SO account questions lol)

Comment: @Viziionary: you just made my day, so grateful to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Jacob's answer is the defacto most efficient solution because if not all of your batched jobs are going to take the same amount of time, his approach will let the threads that finish their task early go back and complete more work as opposed to waiting around doing nothing while the threads with the harder jobs finish.

But just in case anyone wants to know how to properly divide a queue into batches, perhaps for some other use-case, here it is, I used the same queue-pop principle:

```
let dateStart = moment('2004-01-02');
let dateEnd = moment('2008-03-02');
let timeValues = [];
while (dateEnd > dateStart || dateStart.format('M') === dateEnd.format('M')) {
  timeValues.push(dateStart.format('YYYY-MM'));
  dateStart.add(1, 'month');
}
let i = parseInt(process.env.workerId);
let batches = [];
let workerId = 0;
while (timeValues.length > 0) {
  if (!batches[workerId]) batches[workerId] = [];
  batches[workerId].push(timeValues.pop());
  workerId++;
  if (workerId > 15) workerId = 0;
}
let batch = batches[i];
console.log("batch", batch)
```